# Import GeoJSON object into PostGIS in JavaScript

Tags: postgis, javascript, geojson, node-js

I'm looking for a way to persist my GeoJSON object to a table in PostGIS, I've installed the `ogr2ogr` JavaScript library to achieve this; on this case this what I got so far:

```
async function saveBuildFile(geojson) {
  let data = await ogr2ogr(geojson, { format: "PostgreSQL" });
  client.connect();
  const query = SQL`Some query to persist the geojson on a table`;
  await client.query(query);
  client.end();
  console.log("Success");
}
```

I mean what should be the query to persist the data on PostGIS?

UPDATE:
According to the [ogr2ogr library docs](https://github.com/wavded/ogr2ogr) it is possible add some parameters on the options method parameter; anyways I'm have some issues tryng to get this working:

```
async function saveBuildFile(geojson) {
  await ogre2ogr(geojson, {
    format: "PostgreSQL",
    options: [
      "PG:'dbname=mydb host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres password=admin1'",
      "-nln map_table_001",
    ],
  });
```

Comment: You'd need a service that provides this capability for a specific solution. It would be a huge security risk if any web client could start writing arbitrary rows (or worse start executing arbitrary commands).

Comment: I would suggest you look at the WFS protocol

Comment: Is your code called on the server (nodejs) or on the client? If it's on the client you should use a service. If it's on the backend a plain ```INSERT``` should work. In your example, how does the ```data``` statement look like? Be aware that your table in your database needs to have all the columns and that the database is PostGIS enabled.

Comment: Is on a node js server